# How to display a subscription form after few posts in grid blog

Tags: plugin-mailchimp

I am looking to insert a mailchimp subscription form after few (probably 6) post excerpts on a blog something similar to dudeiwantthat.com. I am using generatepress premium theme. Is there anyone who can guide through that. My site is travelgeeky.com

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to touch the loop you could output your optin form after the last post and move it into position with CSS (Flexbox 'order') or jQuery

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to do that?

Comment: @AmitAhuja link?